# How can Openresty get the socket port in proxy server between prroxy server and upstream server?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I use OpenResty® to proxy my backend server.
The process is client->proxy server->backend server

The question is the comment of the code:

```
stream {
    upstream teststream{
        server xxxxxx:1234;
    }

    server {
        listen 1234;
        proxy_pass teststream;

        content_by_lua_block {
            #how to get the proxy server socket port between proxy server and backend server
        }
    }}
```

Client sends a message to proxy server, then proxy server forwards the message to backend server.The proxy server will new a socket to connect the backend server, so how to get the proxy server socket port between proxy server and backend server in content_by_lua_block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is https://github.com/openresty/lua-upstream-nginx-module

> **get_servers**
>
> syntax: servers = upstream.get_servers(upstream_name)
>
> Get configurations for all the servers in the specified upstream
>   group. Please one server may take multiple addresses when its server
>   name can be resolved to multiple addresses.
>
> The return value is an array-like Lua table. Each table entry is a
>   hash-like Lua table that takes the following keys:
>
> - addr
>
> socket address(es). can be either a Lua string or an array-like Lua
>   table of Lua strings.
>
> ...

BTW, both proxy_pass and content_by_lua_block are content phase directives.
Only one will work. Please take a look at this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openresty-en/DRocQpM4mVY